# SELECT the last ID after INSERT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm aware of using RETURNING in an INSERT statement but need a way to either have it returned as a result of the INSERT statement (or enclosing transaction) or be able to retrieve that value using SELECT.  Is there a way to do this?  I cannot use DBMS_OUTPUT.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

RETURNING clause is the easiest way to **guarantee** getting the value of the ID generated by an INSERT statement. Querying for `max(id)` is unreliable in a multi-user environment, especially if you're using RAC.

If the ID is populated from a sequence you can get the current value of the sequence by running this **in the same session** as the INSERT:

```
 select your_sequence.currval from dual;
```

This means you need to know the name of the sequence, which isn't always obvious, even more so if you're using 12c Identity columns.

Basically, if you want the ID use RETURNING.

Comment: Thanks, dumb question here...  How do I become aware of the sequence?

Comment: That's business logic. Unless you're using Oracle 12c Identity columns there's no tie in the data dictionary between a sequence and a primary key. You'll need to check your application logic - PL/SQL API, triggers, etc. [This answer might give you a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363311/146325)

Comment: @APC You didn't mention the fact that the query from DUAL could return a value that his INSERT did not use (e.g., concurrent processes doing similar things). All it takes is two concurrent processes getting the nextval from the sequence. I agree with your final statement but you left the concurrency problem hanging.